# Resize Canvas without Cropping

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I keep running into a problem where I generate an image with canvas however the size will not change when I change it in css.  For example:  Lets say I create a 200px x 200px square image in a canvas.  Then in css I set the dimensions to 100px x 100px.  Rather than scaling the image only 1/4 of the original image is displayed.  How can I get the canvas to scale without actually changing the canvas itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are expected.

*Your rectangle is not being cropped, it's being resized*.

- A 200x200 canvas has 40,000 pixels
- A 100x100 canvas has 10,000 pixels

The smaller canvas is 1/4 the size of the larger canvas and the rect will be 1/4 the size.

Without knowing your design requirements, what you probably want to do is **avoid using CSS to scale your canvas**.  As you've discovered, changing width/height with CSS will "stretch/shrink" the size of your drawings.

Instead, change the canvas element's width/height, not the CSS width/height. When you change the canvas element's width/height any drawing you have already done will be erased (you must redraw those drawings).  But the new drawings will be "correctly" sized.

When you want to resize the canvas (in javascript):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width=100;
canvas.height=100;

// changing the canvas width/height will automatically erase and drawings
// so you must now redraw those drawings.
```

If you want to scale the canvas without having to redraw, you can do this:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width=100;
    canvas.height=100;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
img.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: I actually want to strech my canvas drawing.  But what you said about css "As you've discovered, changing width/height with CSS will 'stretch/shrink' the size of your drawings." Does not work:  http://jsfiddle.net/UxLXt/

Comment: Your fiddle resizes the canvas elements, not the CSS style.  You can shrink with CSS like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Kq5pL/  Cheers!